# Print a report in visual studio

Tags: c#, report

I have a paper form like invoice and I want to print database values on it (by query). So I want to insert the text at special locations like invoice number, company name, amount and ..

for this purpose what is the correct and standard method

1. have windows form with the invoice background image and set the location of thextbox
2. use  Microsoft report  and report viewer (how?)

or any other solution

Thanks in adavance

Comment: I did a similar project where I used Microsoft.Interopt.Word. Just load a Word template and fill in the blanks (Tag replacement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use crystal report. You can configure the location of field while printing in crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Microsoft report have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649551.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options,
a) There are print packages in dreamincode, look at some of them.

b) The recommended way, use crystal report. Much easier and cleaner.